# how to use specific 2 color for pie chart using uicolor?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uicolor

I would like to ask something regarding **UIColor custom method**.  In my project I am creating a pie chart using magic pie chart lib.
Now there is one method for set color for pie chart like

```
CGFloat hue = ( arc4random() % 256 / 256.0 );  //  0.0 to 1.0
CGFloat saturation = ( arc4random() % 128 / 256.0 ) + 0.5;  //  0.5 to 1.0, away from white
CGFloat brightness = ( arc4random() % 128 / 256.0 ) + 0.5;  //  0.5 to 1.0, away from black
return [UIColor colorWithHue:hue saturation:saturation brightness:brightness alpha:1];.
```

My question is rather than using **random color I want to fix two color only** like BLUE Color And Green Color so how to fix it?  I do not want to change color every time when controller load.

Thanks in advance for your kind reply.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on a few things, but one approach might be to replace the function call to the code you posted with fixed UIColors.  If you only need two colours you could have a flag on your controller that indicates colour 1 has been used and will instead use colour 2 next time it is called. i.e.

```
// replace call to random colour code with this, and define a boolean in your class to use as a flag:

if(!someFlag) { 
  someFlag = YES;
  return [UIColor redColor];
}
else {
  someFlag = NO;
  return [UIColor blueColor];
}
```

Comment: hello BinaryGuy thank you for your valuable response but i am not able to understand if i am using like above solution at a time only one color is showing in pie chart. e.g if i want to show like ratio of expanse and income money.so its is showing only blue and if flag is NO than red color

Comment: It's hard to give advice because I don't know your code, but I imagine it's not working because the flag is not being persisted across calls to this function due to an object being intialised each time.  You somehow need to make the someFlag variable 'permanent' so that you can count on it switching each time you try to get a new colour.